# Proximity search in Postgresql for Street Addresses

Tags: sql, postgresql, proximity, haversine

I have a list of street addresses with city and state but no zip code. These addresses won't geocode with Google's API because they are building permit addresses with no mailbox or new construction addresses they have yet to be built.

I would like to do a kind of proximity search that will find the nearest address which does have a geocode. Is this possible?

I've read about doing this with zip codes but I don't have those and I am worried they are still too general.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like each of these requires a lat/long to do the proximity search. I don't have that. Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: Ah, I see how that was confusing. I meant I want to find the closest location with a possible lat/long.

Comment: How precise do you need to get? You can try to geocode the address (street without the number, city, state), it will probably give you a rough approximation. You can also try the address with the street number, decrementing/incrementing until you find the closest neighbours. Note that you should still have a ZIP code, a ZIP is a pretty large area (as opposed to a ZIP+4 which is a lot more specific).

Comment: Did you check OSM data? Check please if there are addresses in osm in this area you need geocoding - if so it's nothing difficult to import this data into postgis and write some procedure which will do the job...